# Storing IndexedDB databses on the SD card

Tags: sd-card, indexeddb, firefox-os

I would like to store a few gigabytes of data as cache for offline usage in a Firefox OS application. My Alcatel One Touch Fire with Firefox OS 1.3 stores IndexedDB databases in the quite limited internal memory.

Is it possible to store IndexedDB databases on the SD card? How? (Maybe newer Firefox OS versions supports it?)

Comment: @RaymondCamden: Thanks for the comment. I would accept it as an answer too, consider writing it, please.

Comment: Done (and more chars to make it a valid comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the IDB spec doesn't allow you to specify where the data is stored. The browser determines it.